# Remove string in object for specific values

Tags: javascript, mongoose, replace, find

I have the following javascript object

```
{
  priceValue: { '$gt': '500' },
  '$text': { '$search': 'black iphone' }
}
```

From which I need to remove the strings from $text and $search so that it becomes

```
{
  priceValue: { '$gt': '500' },
  $text: { $search: 'black iphone' }
}
```

In order for mongoose to query the user response correctly.

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Those are the same in JavaScript.

Comment: As mentioned above, all object keys are strings in JS so what you're asking for doesn't make any sense. After removing the quotes, what data type are you expecting them to be?

Comment: I see, yes I was coming to the same conclusion. My initial thought was that mongoose was not recognizing it with the strings around them.